# Is possible to construct a polynomial that erases basis information for any multivector?

Tags: clifford-algebras

Let me give two quick examples. Let $\mathbf{u}_1$ and $\mathbf{u}_2$ be a multivectors of $Cl_{3,0}(\mathbb{R})$:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{u}_1&=x e_1+y e_2\\
\mathbf{u}_2&=a+be_1
\end{align}
$$

---

For $\mathbf{u}_1$, I can construct a polynomial (of degree 2) that erases all basis elements, simply by taking the geometric product:

$$
\mathbf{u}_1^2 = x^2+y^2
$$

---

For $\mathbf{u}_2$ this is also possible as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{u}_2^2&=a^2+b^2+2abe_1\\
\mathbf{u}_2^2&=a(2a+2be_1)-a^2+b^2\\
\mathbf{u}_2^2&=a(2\mathbf{u})-a^2+b^2\\
\mathbf{u}_2^2-2a\mathbf{u}+a^2-b^2&=0
\end{align}
$$

---

Of course, as a restriction, the original value of $\mathbf{u}_1$ and $\mathbf{u}_2$ must be a root of the polynomial. Bonus points if the produced polynomial is the lowest degree possible.

---

Is it possible to produce such a polynomial when we are talking about the most general multivector of say $Cl_{3,0}(\mathbb{R})$ or even $Cl_{3,1}(\mathbb{R})$:

$$
\mathbf{u}:=a\\
+t\gamma_0+x\gamma_1+y\gamma_2+z\gamma_3\\
+E_x\gamma_0\gamma_1+E_y\gamma_0\gamma_2+E_z\gamma_0\gamma_3\\
+B_x\gamma_2\gamma_3+B_y\gamma_1\gamma_3+B_z\gamma_1\gamma_2\\
+V_t\gamma_0+V_x\gamma_1+V_y\gamma_2+V_z\gamma_3\\
+b\gamma_0\gamma_1\gamma_2\gamma_3
$$

---

**EDIT**

Finding the roots of a complex number in $Cl_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ by solving a polynomial:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{u}:&=a+bI=a+b\sigma_x\sigma_y\sigma_z\\
\implies \mathbf{u}^2&=a^2-b^2+2abI\\
&=a(2a+2bI-a)-b^2\\
&=a(2\mathbf{u}-a)-b^2\\
&=2a\mathbf{u}-a^2-b^2\\
\implies \mathbf{u}^2-2a\mathbf{u}+a^2+b^2&=0\\
\implies \mathbf{u}&=a\pm\sqrt{-b^2}=a\pm ib
\end{align}
$$

Finding the eigenvalues of the matrix representation of $\mathbf{u}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{u}=a\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}+b\pmatrix{i&0\\0&i}=\pmatrix{a+ib&0\\0&a+ib}
\end{align}
$$

The eigenvalues are the same: $a+ib$

The roots of the polynomial are not the same as the eigenvalues. Can I use the matrix representation to solve for the roots of the polynomial? This would be a different equation to solve than the equation of the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Any Clifford algebra is isomorphic to a subalgebra of a matrix algebra, so the Cayley-Hamilton theorem applies.

Comment: @mr_e_man That's very clever, thanks.

Comment: @mr_e_man I actually did notice the similarity between my question, and between solving the matrix representation for its eigenvalues. However, I was able to find a counterexample. The roots of the multivector $v=a+b\sigma_x\sigma_y\sigma_z$ for $Cl_{3,0}(\mathbb{R})$ solved as a polynomial, are different than the eigenvalues of the matrix representation of $v$. Let me edit my question to show the difference.

Comment: @mr_e_man edit made to my question. Due to the discrepancy between the results, is the  Cayley-Hamilton theorem still applicable?

Comment: @mr_e_man nevermind, I think I found my mistake. And thanks for the help. Obviously if I start with $u=a+bi$ then I cannot end with $u=a\pm bi$ later...